# $Resource in communities : bug?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

The following code used to work perfectly from CRM & from communities

```
<ltng:require styles="{!join(',',
        $Resource.bootstrap + '/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        $Resource.resource +'/resource/css/irm-style.css' ,
        $Resource.resource +'/resource/css/irm-style-new.css'
    )}"
    scripts="{!join(',',
        $Resource.jquery,
        $Resource.momentJS
    )}" />
```

But since Spring 17 upgrade, rewrited URL doubles the name of the community :

> ex:  GET
>   https://xxxxxxxx-developer-edition.eu11.force.com/distributor/distributor/resource/1486435172000/bootstrap/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css

distributor is the name of the community, and is strangely written twice in the URL generated from `$Resource`

Is my code wrong / not supported anymore ?

Comment: I have the same issue in my sandboxes since Wednesday. Since today I also have the issue in production. I contacted Premier Support, but so far I haven't received a solution.

Comment: I solved it temporary replacing $Resource.resname by '/resource/resname' , but I have it in lots of places so i'd prefer SFDC to publish a fix than if we have to update all our code ^^

Comment: I have the same issue, and same temporary fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce has identified it as a bug and created a known issue for it:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C99QAE